# run neo4j with docker-compose - neo4j not accessible from localhost:7474

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose, dockerfile

---EDITED --  NO LONGER WORKING --- PLEASE HELP--- 
maybe something is changed in the latest neo4j image (SE MY ANSWER BELOW FOR MORE DETAILS)

I'm try to run neo4j with docker-compose by means of this github repo (that contains the docker-compose.yml)

https://github.com/GraphRM/workshop-neo4j-docker

The docker-compose file conteined in this repo is nothing more that a plain neo4j docker image with some data already attached (you can try yourself, the image is realy small)

Running this file `docker-compose up -d` (from the folder where the `docker-compose.yml` file is) seems that all gone well (No errors are showed and the output of the console is `Starting workshopneo4jdocker_neo4j_1 ... done`)
but in the browser nothing is showed at the following addresses:

```
localhost:7474
0.0.0.0:7474
127.0.0.1:7474
<dockermachine ip>:7474    got this address with `docker-machine ip`
```

I suppose is it a network problem (wrong ip address or something related)  so i've noted that in the docker-compose.yml file is missing the element `network_mode:`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:latest
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    environment:
      - NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.*
      - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true
      - NEO4J_dbms_shell_enabled=true
    volumes:
      - ./plugins:/plugins
      - ./data:/data
      - ./import:/import
```

I'd like to modify this file adding `network_mode: "bridge"`  or test with other values (`host,none,service:[service name],container:[container name/id]`)

but the question now is:

how to modify this file if the `nano` editor is not installed in the neo4j docker image and i can't even install it because `apt-get` is not installed as well.
(it is a really very minimal image)

Morovere i'm not a linux user so i don't know how to modyfy this file.
May you suggest me the way to modify this file on an image that does't have these tools **without using vim**?

I'm not so expert with linux but i need to run this `docker-compose.yml` file provided with the above github repo.

**MY ENVIROMENT**

```
Docker Toobox for windows
`docker version`
Client:
 Version:       18.01.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    03596f51b1
 Built: Thu Jan 11 22:29:41 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.01.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   03596f5
  Built:        Wed Jan 10 20:13:12 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

PS: do you think the problem is not related to the ip address?

**>>>>>EDITED<<<<<**

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
38e06d1020d8        neo4j:latest        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   30 hours ago        Up 29 minutes       0.0.0.0:7474->7474/tcp, 7473/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7687->7687/tcp   workshopneo4jdocker_neo4j_1
```

Comment: looks good. Could you please provide `docker ps` output?

Comment: @BukharovSergey i've added the `ps` output to the post above

Comment: thanks. container ports forwarded successfully. `0.0.0.0:7474->7474/tcp`. It must be accessable by `localhost:7474` or `127.0.0.1:7474` from web browser. all of your configuration looks ok. I think it is docker-windows issue. You can try to downgrade docker to `17.12.0-ce` or run container at `Linux` machine

Comment: Docker toolbox for windows install a virtualbox machine so the container already run on a Linux machine

Comment: If the previous solution is not working anymore, ask a new question referring to this one. Don't edit this question or add "answers" to it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding `network_mode: "bridge"` to the `docker-compose.yml` file and accessing to the docker-machine ip the image works correctly

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:latest
    network_mode: "bridge"
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    environment:
      - NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.*
      - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true
      - NEO4J_dbms_shell_enabled=true
    volumes:
      - ./plugins:/plugins
      - ./data:/data
      - ./import:/import
```

Comment: only for docker-compose up

Answer (score 1):

Below yml file work fine to me. Yes it is not very fast and you have to wait for 2-3 minutes for it to come up and available to browser at *http://localhost:7474/browser*

```
version: '3'


services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:4.3.3-community #4.3.3-community  latest
    container_name: neo4j
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    networks:
      - ecosystem_network
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/eco_system
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=512M
    volumes:
      - ${HOME}/neo4j/data:/data 
      - ${HOME}/neo4j/logs:/logs 
      - ${HOME}/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import 
      - ${HOME}/neo4j/plugins:/plugins 

    

networks:
  ecosystem_network:
    driver: bridge
```