# Neo4j docker-compose image refusing connection to application

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose

I used to run Neo4j separately and then my application interacted with it as required. Now I am using `docker-compose` to run `Neo4j`.

Here's my portion of `neo4j` in docker file.

```
  neo4j:
    container_name: neo4j_container
    restart: always
    image: neo4j:3.5.3
    network_mode: "bridge"
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "6477:6477"
      - "7687:7687"
      - "7473:7473"
    environment:
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.*
      - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true
      - NEO4J_dbms_shell_enabled=true
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7474
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6477
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7687
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/abc/temp:/var/lib/neo4j/import
```

The image of `Neo4j` I am using, as you can see is `neo4j:3.5.3`.
When I try to access `neo4j` after `docker-compose up` from `localhost:7474`, it works totally fine. 
But when I try to access it through my application, it gives the following error

```
Unable to connect to localhost:7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.<br>
```

Tried taking help from this question, but even [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465046/run-neo4j-with-docker-compose-neo4j-not-accessible-from-localhost7474) didn't help.
Here's the `docker-compose ps` output:
[image]
Please tell me if I am missing something?

Comment: Have you tried connecting from your application using machine-ip:7687

Comment: wow, it worked. You can put that in answer and i will accept, if possible tell me what the actual problem was? Also, one more thing please, see the import address in my docker image? It should pick `csv` file from `/usr/local/abc/temp/output.csv` instead it's trying to find file from `/var/lib/neo4j/import/usr/local/polymer/temp/user-data9693_output.csv`. You can asnwer that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56699068/10190191).

Comment: Done, updated my answer. Will check that `csv` file issue.

Comment: fixed the csv issue, thanks tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `machine-ip:7687` in your application to connect to `neo4j`.

In your case `neo4j` is running in [bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#use-the-default-bridge-network) networking mode, in which the container network is different from that of host network. So in order to access application running inside such container from outside world, you have to do [port mapping](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) which you did using `ports:` field in docker-compose.

Now I guess the application which is trying to access `neo4j` is also running in `bridge` networking mode. So putting `localhost:7687` in your application will point to `localhost` of that container, but you want to connect to `neo4j` container port 7687 which we have already mapped to host network using `ports` option. In this case your `neo4j` port 7687 can e accessed using `machine-ip:7687` from outside world.

Hope this helps.